# Error Message: TF255235 While manually importing TFS2008 db into TFS2012

Tags: tfs

While I was upgrading from TFS2008 to TFS2012 I received an error stating:

> Upgrade Failure: "The installation and configuration of Team
>   Foundation Server succeeded, however upgrading the data was
>   unsuccessful"

I then found that you can not rerun the upgrade wizard. How can you rerun the update?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost BACK UP YOUR DATABASES! REALLY!

At this point I turned to the tfsconfig import command. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407080.aspx)

I specifically ran:

> TFSConfig Import /SQLInstance:TFS01 (my server name)
>   /CollectionName:(Anything you want) /confirmed

But I then got this error message:

> Errors:1 Error Message: TF255235: Database TfsVersionControl on TFS01
>   does not exist but the current operation requires an existing
>   database.

So not only did the original upgrade not work, it also killed one of my DBs. That's fine because I have a backup. So open up SSMS and kill whatever database is pointing to the "TfsVersionControl.mdf" file. Then kill the actual mdf and ldf files.

Next, restore TfsVersionControl again from the database. At this point, we are reset back to pre-upgrade...

Now for the work around. It is an easy but ugly one. In SSMS make the user that is running TFS (in my case tfsService a sysadmin). That's it.

Go back into the command window and rerun the import. About 20 minutes later viola it worked perfectly.

Make sure that you remove the sysadmin permission from the user after everything is working perfectly.

I hope this helps someone.